# onclick & ondblclick js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу выполнить функцию по двойному нажатию на элемент не выполняя onclick.

```js
function one() {
  console.log("one");
}

function two() {
  console.log("two");
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="one()" ondblclick="two()">
  CLICK
</div>
```

Comment: [_From jQuery docs but related:"It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the click and dblclick events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies from browser to browser, with some receiving two click events before the dblclick and others only one. Double-click sensitivity (maximum time between clicks that is detected as a double click) can vary by operating system and browser, and is often user-configurable."_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699677/call-ondblclick-without-calling-onclick-event#comment27550049_18699677)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал так

```js
function one() {
  console.log("one");
  timerId = clearTimeout(timerId)
}

function two() {
  console.log("two");
  timerId = clearTimeout(timerId)
}
let timerId = null;

function handlerClick() {
  if (!timerId) {
    timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      one()
    }, 200);
  } else {
    two()
  }

}
```

```html
<div onclick="handlerClick()">
  CLICK
</div>
```

Comment: Неплохой вариант, но с таймером не то, видна задержка, т.к в функциях так же выполняется добавление/удаление стилей.

Comment: как мне видится - эту проблему не решить по-другому. Можно только уменьшить время задержки.